# Import data until certain row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a long data set and need to import data into a dataframe until a specific row.

| Time | data |
| --- | --- |
| 08:00 | 12 |
| 09:00 | 34 |
| 10:00 | 23 |
| 08-10 | 45 |
| 11:00 | 56 |
| 12:00 | 23 |

I need to get the data when importing the excel file until Time=08-10 and igonre all other rows

| Time | data |
| --- | --- |
| 08:00 | 12 |
| 09:00 | 34 |
| 10:00 | 23 |
| 08-10 | 45 |

That is what I am trying to use:

```
data=pd.read_excel("2019-data.xls",sheet_name="110", header=4)
```

However, I have different sheets in which the location of the "08-10" row vary and I am not sure how to address this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), comapre by value and then [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html), invert mask and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df  = df[~df['Time'].shift().eq('08-10').cummax()]
print (df)
    Time  data
0  08:00    12
1  09:00    34
2  10:00    23
3  08-10    45
```